# wp plugin adds "pagespeed.css" after each css file

Tags: plugins, css

I have installed some wp page speed optimization plugins to my website. Now the website works faster, however one of the plugins adds its own file name ending, like this one: `styles.css.pagespeed.cf.M0Q5l-FwhO.css`. I tried disabling all plugins I thought might be somehow related to the question, but nothing changed. Also, the plugin modifies all media files names same way, e.g.: `picture.jpg.pagespeed.F0K2c-zkg8.jpg`

Has anyone encountered such problem before?

Comment: "Problem"? Isn't this literally how the pagespeed module is supposed to work?

Comment: To me it is a problem since I can not find where I could change any settings related to it

Comment: This is how pagespeed works.